# How to decode String?

Tags: java, jsp, url, utf8-decode

Hi i am trying to fetch an url  by which i am getting  a string i am trying to decode that   string but  whole string is not decoding  how can i decode whole string decode

Here is my code

**geturl.jsp**

```
<%

    URL url;

    try {
        // get URL content

        String a = "http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandim/MarketWise?m=agra";
        url = new URL(a);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String str = new String(inputLine.getBytes(), "utf-8");
            out.println(str);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

i am getting following output

```
धान~1325|चावल~2050|ज�?वर~920|जौ~810|मकई~1280|गेहू�?~1420|जो~1050|बेजर~-|जय~800|उड़द~3600|मूंग~4400|चाना~3400|मटर~2700|अरहर~4100|मसूर~2000|लोबिया(बीज)~-|सोयाबीन~-|ढे�?चा(बीज)~-
```

here i am getting  some ? symbol

**Desired output**

```
धान~1325|चावल~2050|ज्वर~920|जौ~810|मकई~1280|गेहूँ~1420|जो~1050|बेजर~-|जय~800|उड़द~3600|मूंग~4400|चाना~3400|मटर~2700|अरहर~4100|मसूर~2000|लोबिया(बीज)~-|सोयाबीन~-|ढेँचा(बीज)~-
```

How can i get my desired output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the encoding when you create he reader:

```
new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Don't try to do any other conversions.

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that the encoding is "UTF-8", then use @Joni's solution.

But a more technically correct solution is to:

1. use `conn.getHeaderField("content-type")` to extract the response mediatype,
2. extract the `charset` parameter (if any), and
3. use that as the charset for decoding the response input stream.

At the same time you should probably check that the mediatype is what you are expecting and check the response status code.

References:

- The Content-type header: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17
- The syntax of a `mediatype` string: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7

Answer (score 0):

You are able to see many of the characters with utf-8 encoding, except few. So make sure you ,in your system, proper fonts have been installed that supports all these.